# mount cifs: input/output error

Tags: linux, fedora, mount

I'm running fedora 20. I can connect successfully to a shared Windows folder via `files > connect to server`; however, when I try mounting the share manually I get various errors:

```
sudo mount.cifs //<ip>/<share> /mnt/windows -o user=<user>
```

returns (after inputting *correct* password):

`mount error(13): Permission denied`

```
sudo mount.cifs //<ip>/<share> /mnt/windows -o user=<user>,domain=<company domain>
```

returns:

`mount error(5): Input/output error`

I've also tried the obvious things of `sec=ntlm` and checking the firewall, but to no avail... any suggestions as to what I'm missing?!

Comment: Hmmm....I feel that I have seen this one before.

Comment: I checked the answers to similar questions but none of the answers provided worked for me - in particular none of them included a domain It's specifically the different errors between supplying and not supplying a domain which confused me